# Why does `if (guess != 'a' || guess != 'A' || ...)` not work?

Tags: java

Here is my code, I know the if statement is really long and the code could probably be more efficient, but I just want to know the answer to this as it is driving me nuts.

```
while (whileloop == 1)
  {
    if (guess != 'a' || guess != 'A' || guess != 'b' || guess != 'B' || guess != 'c' || guess != 'C' || guess != 'd' || guess != 'D' || guess != 'e' || guess != 'E' || guess != 'f' || guess != 'F' || guess != 'g' || guess != 'G' || guess != 'h' || guess != 'H' || guess != 'i' || guess != 'I' || guess != 'j' || guess != 'J' || guess != 'k' || guess != 'K' || guess != 'l' || guess != 'L' || guess != 'm' || guess != 'M' || guess != 'n' || guess != 'N' || guess != 'o' || guess != 'O' ||guess != 'p' || guess != 'P' || guess != 'q' || guess != 'Q' || guess != 'r' || guess != 'R' || guess != 's' || guess != 'S' || guess != 't' || guess != 'T' || guess == ' ')
    {
      System.out.println ("\nNot a Point. Try again.");
      guess = IBIO.inputChar ("If the missile is launched from Point B, which Point will the missile hit? ");
    }
    else 
      whileloop = 2;
  }
```

Comment: What is the expected behavior?

Comment: You should really look into using regular expressions to simplify your code. This is simply not readable or maintainable.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Because you wanted a logical and `&&` (not a logical or `||`). When you use `||` if any condition is `true` (such as the letter A not being the letter B, the entire expression is true). You could use an `||` with two ands. Something like

```
 if (!(guess >= 'a' && guess <= 'z') || !(guess >= 'A' && guess <= 'Z'))
```

Comment: Thanks this really helped!  Gosh I was being stupid

Comment: @HrithikShah Please accept Elliott's answer if you think it is correct :-)